# Expected spy navigate to have been called with: [ [ '/summary' ] ] but it was never called

Tags: angular

I'm trying to test my method. This is what my method looks like:

```
public async uploadFile() {
    console.log('uploadFile');
    this.isGeneratingResponse = true;
    this.disableUpload = true;
    this.errorMessage = '';

    const base64String = await this.pdfToBase64TransformerService.convertPdfToBase64(this.selectedFile!);

    console.log('base64String', base64String);
    const subscription = this
    .pdfSummarizerService
    .summarizePdf(base64String)
    .subscribe({
      next: (response) => {

        console.log('>>> test', response);
        this.isGeneratingResponse = false;

        console.log('setting summary');
        this.summaryService.setSummary(response.summary);
        console.log('refreshing user credits');
        this.userCreditsService.refreshUserCredits();
        this.router.navigate(['/summary']);
      },
      error: (error) => {
        this.errorMessage = error.error.message;
        this.disableUpload = false;
        this.isGeneratingResponse = false;
      }
    });

    this.subscriptions.push(subscription);
  }
```

I'm using `ngneat/spectator` in my test. By for some reason angular isn't detecting that the methods are getting called. I tried to print or use console.log and I'm able to see the logs like `setting summary`, so I'm pretty sure those methods are getting called. Can someone tell me what I did wrong? My understanding is with `spectator.inject()` I should be able to get an instance of the service and from there I can return values and check if they're ever getting called, but I'm only getting the error:

```
Expected spy refreshUserCredits to have been called.

Expected spy setSummary to have been called.

Expected spy navigate to have been called with:
  [ [ '/summary' ] ]
but it was never called.
```

Here's what my test looks like:

```
let spectator: Spectator<DashboardComponent>;

  const userInfo = {
    id: '1234',
    username: 'Cypher',
    dateCreated: new Date().toISOString(),
    emailAddress: 'Cypher@gmail.com'
  } as UserInfo;

  const newUserCredits = {
    userId: '12345',
    maxCredits: 1,
    creditsUsed: 0,
    creditsRemaining: 1,
  } as UserCredits;

  const createComponent = createComponentFactory({
    component: DashboardComponent,
    providers: [
      mockProvider(PdfToBase64TransformerService),
      mockProvider(PdfSummarizerService),
      mockProvider(UserCreditsService, {
        userCredits$: of(newUserCredits)
      }),
      mockProvider(SummaryService),
      mockProvider(Router),
      mockProvider(UserInfoService, {
        userInfo$: of(userInfo)
      })
    ],
    declarations: [
      MockComponents(CreditInfoComponent)
    ]
  });

// other code here.

it('should upload the file when clicked and redirect to the summary page.', () => {
      spectator = createComponent();
      const file = new File([''], 'file1.pdf', { type: 'application/pdf' });
      spectator.component.selectedFile = file;

      const pdfToBase64TransformerService = spectator.inject(PdfToBase64TransformerService);
      pdfToBase64TransformerService.convertPdfToBase64.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve('some base64'));

      const pdfSummarizerService = spectator.inject(PdfSummarizerService);
      pdfSummarizerService.summarizePdf.and.returnValue(of('some summary'));

      const summaryService = spectator.inject(SummaryService);
      const router = spectator.inject(Router);
      const userCreditsService = spectator.inject(UserCreditsService);

      spectator.component.uploadFile();
      spectator.detectChanges();

      // this expectation fails.
      expect(userCreditsService.refreshUserCredits).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(summaryService.setSummary).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/summary']);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using `async` and `whenStable`. Here's the complete code:

```
it('should upload the file when clicked and redirect to the summary page.', async () => {
      spectator = createComponent();
      const file = new File([''], 'file1.pdf', { type: 'application/pdf' });
      spectator.component.selectedFile = file;

      const pdfToBase64TransformerService = spectator.inject(PdfToBase64TransformerService);
      pdfToBase64TransformerService.convertPdfToBase64.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve('some base64'));

      const pdfSummarizerService = spectator.inject(PdfSummarizerService);
      pdfSummarizerService.summarizePdf.and.returnValue(of({
        summary: 'some summary'
      }));

      const summaryService = spectator.inject(SummaryService);
      summaryService.setSummary.and.callFake((test) => {
        console.log('caaalling...', test)
      });

      const router = spectator.inject(Router);
      router.navigate.and.callFake((test) => {
        console.log('beef', test)
      });

      const userCreditsService = spectator.inject(UserCreditsService);

      spectator.component.uploadFile();
      spectator.fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        expect(userCreditsService.refreshUserCredits).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(summaryService.setSummary).toHaveBeenCalledWith('some summary');
        expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/summary']);
      });

    });
```